# How to calculate Average of a column while ignoring the error in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a table in PowerBI as shown in the first screenshot above. I want to calculate the average WA (Weighted Average) for both Topic 1 and 2. After obtain the average value, then I want to plot the value in the column chart together with the weighted average for Topic 1 and 2 as shown in the second screenshot. The weighted average for Topic 1 is `0.43` while for Topic 2 is `0.50`, hence the Average for both Topic 1 and Topic 2 should be `0.465 ~ 0.47`.

One of the challenging here is that my data consist of error `NaN`, so somehow need to ignore the `NaN` when doing the calculation for Average value.

I'm still new to DAX, hope to get some help and advice on this problem, thank you!

Comment: Did you tried visual level filter to exclude rows where value = NaN?

Comment: I'm using `AVERAGEX(Table, Table[WA])` to calculate the average. Before I do the filtering, there is no bar in the chart, only label. After I filter the visual by using the `WA`, the entire column chart disappear

Comment: can you try with something like -  AVERAGEX(filter(Table, WA <> "NaN"), Table[WA])

Comment: yes thank you, it is working now:D, do you want to post your answer so that I can accept your solution.

Comment: Sure :) My pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with some DAX code as below-

```
AVERAGEX(filter(Table, WA <> "NaN"), Table[WA])
```